# How to install imagick in cpanel? Interserver

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick, imagick

I have Installed Imagick in my WHM with php pecl. But when i using imagick it through error "You need to install the imagick extension to use this back end"

I treid to enable extension in my cpanel. But in my cpanel does not have this tool "Select PHP Versions"

Answer (score 0):

If its Linux based and you have command line access in cpanel then you can try installing it via the command line using the following command

```
sudo yum install php-imagick
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by restart apache
using this comand
/scripts/restartsrv_apache_php_fpm